# AngularJS controller unit test with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm making a unit test for an angular controller with Jasmine but I can't get passed the error

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'running' of undefined".

The full error is posted at the bottom.

Here's the app definition...

```
var myApp= myApp|| angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

myApp.run(['$http', '$rootScope', 'properties', function($http, $rootScope, properties) {
    //...
    //Implementation of custom dependency
    properties.get().then(function(response) {
        $rootScope.propertiesLoaded = true;
        myApp.properties = response;
    });
   //...
}]);
```

The controller..

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, users) {
    //...
});
```

The test.js

```
describe("Test Controllers", function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.module("myApp");

        //Injection of mocked custom dependency into the myApp.run method
        myApp.run(function ($provide) {
            $provide.provider('properties', function () {
                this.$get = function () {
                    return "Mock return"
                };
            });
        });
    });

    describe("myController", function () {
        var scope, usrs, createMainController, mockDependency;

        beforeEach(function () {
            mockDependency = {
                current: {
                    get: function () {
                        return "Mock return";
                    }
                }
            };

            angular.module(function ($provide) {
                $provide.value('users', mockDependency);
            },[]);

            inject(function (_$injector_, _$controller_, _$rootScope_, users) {
                scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
                usrs = _$injector_.get("users");

                _$controller_("myController", {
                    $scope: scope,
                    users: usrs
                });

                createMainController = function () {
                    return _$controller_("myController", {
                        $scope: scope,
                        users: usrs
                    });
                };
            });

        });

        describe("This simple test", function () {
            it("should pass no matter what", function () {
                expect(true).toBe(true);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the whole error message...

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'running' of undefined
    at isSpecRunning (file:///C:/.../angular-mocks.js:1923:73)
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (file:///C:/.../angular-mocks.js:2087:20)`
***Next line points to inject function***
    `at Object.<anonymous> (file:///C:/.../mySpec.js:37:13)
    at attemptSync (file:///C:/.../jasmine.js:1510:12)
    at QueueRunner.run (file:///C:/.../jasmine.js:1498:9)
    at QueueRunner.execute (file:///C:/.../jasmine.js:1485:10)
    at Spec.Env.queueRunnerFactory (file:///C:/.../jasmine.js:518:35)
    at Spec.execute (file:///C:/.../jasmine.js:306:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///C:/.../jasmine.js:1708:37)
    at attemptAsync (file:///C:/.../jasmine.js:1520:12)`

Here is a related reference to the error that I found which suggests it is an existing problem with Jasmine. However, in this case the problem involved Mocha, which I'm not using.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1467

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will help you, but you could give this a shot, I've had that problem. I'm not very good with AngularJS so if this doesn't work I don't know what to tell you. In your angular-mocks.js find the function isSpecRunning and change it into this:

```
function isSpecRunning() {
  //return currentSpec && (window.mocha || currentSpec.queue.running);
  return !!currentSpec;
}
```

I read something about Jasmine 2.0 (not sure if that's what you're on) not behaving unless you have this line.

They have fixed this issue using the above logic in newer version of [angular-mocks.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-mocks.js) (v 1.3.15).

Comment: Thanks, it looks like that worked. Hopefully that gets fixed, I don't like having to alter any angular files

Comment: This can't be the right solution...not downvoting but this doesn't seem right.

Comment: The limited knowledge I have with Jasmine is that they seem to have an issue on there side that hasn't been addressed besides for work arounds. I too dislike my own method of changing the file, but that's just what I found to be a solution. There's a nice discussion over at https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/issues/492